# symfony2 entity customized function: call to undefined function error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I am trying to add 3 functions for slugifying non-ascii characters in the url, but my slugify function doesn't recognize the sanitize() function although they are in the same scope.:|

```
class Blog
{
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="blog")
    */
    protected $comments;
    ...
    public function slugify($text)
    {
        return sanitize($text);
    }
    ...
    public function sanitize($title) 
    {
        $title = strip_tags($title);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I can't load the fixtures and I get an exception which says "call to undefined function ..\sanitize() in ..\Entity\Blog.php ..."

why this happens? i even tried these: clearing the cache, dropping the database, recreating database, recreating schemas, recreating entities, reloading the fixtures...
but all I've got is the same error:(

can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing the `$this` from your return statement. When calling `sanitize()` without `$this` it's resolving to the method scope and not the class scope.

```
class Blog
{
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="blog")
    */
    protected $comments;
    ...
    public function slugify($text)
    {
        return $this->sanitize($text);
    }
    ...
    public function sanitize($title) 
    {
        $title = strip_tags($title);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```